# Hive View query is not using partition

Tags: hive, explain

I have hive tables and views on top of that tables . When executing query on Table using where clause for partition columns , I see from explain plain that query  is using partition column . But same query when running on view , it is showing from explain plan that there is no use of partition key.
Please suggest

Sample code here , views are created on table with all columns filtered by country code in where clause ( Select * from  where country_code='XX')

Query used for table

```
SELECT a.unique_id,
  a.country_code,
  a.rpt_prd,
  a.abv_cut_off_scor_flag,
  a.acct_und_promo_flag,
.
.
  b.arrg_cob_dt,
  b.arrg_id
 from 
 a
inner join 
 b
on a.country_code   = b.country_code
and a.product_code  = b.product_code
and a.rpt_prd       =b.rpt_prd
and a.unique_id     =b.unique_id
and a.arrg_id       = b.arrg_id
WHERE a.country_code='XX'
AND a.product_code  = 'YYYYY'
AND a.rpt_prd       ='20171231' ;

a
======================================
Partition Key for - a
 PARTITIONED BY (                                   |
|   `country_code` string,                           |
|   `product_code` string,                           |
|   `rpt_prd` string,                                |
|   `unique_id` string)  

b
=======================================
 PARTITIONED BY (                                   |
|   `country_code` string,                           |
|   `product_code` string,                           |
|   `rpt_prd` string,                                |
|   `unique_id` string)  



Query using Views:
===================

SELECT a.unique_id,
  a.country_code,
  a.rpt_prd,
  a.abv_cut_off_scor_flag,
  a.acct_und_promo_flag,
.
.
  b.arrg_cob_dt,
  b.arrg_id
from 
 a
inner join 
 b
on a.country_code   = b.country_code
and a.product_code  = b.product_code
and a.rpt_prd       =b.rpt_prd
and a.unique_id     =b.unique_id
and a.arrg_id       = b.arrg_id
WHERE a.country_code='XX'
AND a.product_code  = 'YYYYY'
AND a.rpt_prd       ='20171231' ;
```

Comment: You should add some code ...

Comment: add views creation script and your query ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the view is working with the same base data as the actual table it ***ought*** to make use of the partition. That said, [other people have had this issue](http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/142bzv6m6g/views-and-partitions-and-performance)

One possible workaround would be to make the view explicitly aware of the partition by creating a [partitioned view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/PartitionedViews) Syntax looks like:

```
ALTER VIEW view_name ADD PARTITION (partition_col = column_name)
```